# How can I upload an image in GUI-PyQt4?

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

I can't upload an image in GUI-PyQt4. It is not able to write the image in the label_97.
please help to solve this issue.

```
def uploadsignsCheck(self):
    fileName = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self.label_97, 'Open File',"/usr/tmp","Images (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.bmp *.gif)")
    fname = image.open(fileName)
    data = fname.read()
    self.label_97.setpixmap(data)
    self.label_97.fname.write(data)
    fname.close()
    print(" pushButton_3 Clicked !")
```

Comment: change `setpixmap` to `setPixmap`

Comment: What is `image`? And what are you trying to do with the line `self.label_97.fname.write(data)`?! If `label_97` is a `QLabel`, you just need to do `self.label_97.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(fileName))`. There is no need to open and read the image data.

Comment: after running this i am getting this error                                   abc@abc-Vostro-3268:~/Desktop$ python sdv.py
QImage::QImage(), XPM is not supported
 pushButton_3 Clicked !

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter the path of your image in setPixmap no need, to write the image data into it.

```
def uploadsignsCheck(self):
    fileName = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self.label_97, 'Open File',"/usr/tmp","Images (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.bmp *.gif)")
    self.label_97.setPixmap(fileName)  # path goes here
    print(" pushButton_3 Clicked !")
```

Comment: after running this i am getting this error                                                                                         abc@abc-Vostro-3268:~/Desktop$ python sdv.py QImage::QImage(), XPM is not supported pushButton_3 Clicked !

Comment: @StellaJoseph try this code with different image format.

Comment: It's not working it says "QImage::QImage(), XPM is not supported".